# Why does the JSON module quote some numbers but not others?

Tags: json, perl

We recently switched to the new JSON2 perl module.
I thought all and everything gets returned quoted now.
But i encountered some cases in which a number (`250`) got returned as unquoted number in the json string created by perl.

Out of curiosity:
**Does anyone know why such cases exist and how the json module decides if to quote a value?**

Comment: Was the number unquoted in your source data structure? And btw, what "new JSON2 module"?

Comment: the number was unquoted in the source data structure. well, JSON2 is new to us - because of the work we had to put into a json module update we waited till now

Comment: There is no module in CPAN named "JSON2". There are at least two modules with "JSON2" in their names. And there's a module "JSON", whose current version is 2.59. What exactly do you mean by "JSON2"? If you mean version 2 of "JSON", please update your question to say so.

Comment: @Keith: i am talking about the JSON module - the number just specifies its version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force it into a string by doing something like this:

```perl
$number_str = '' . $number;
```

For example:

```perl
perl -MJSON -le 'print encode_json({foo=>123, bar=>"".123})'
{"bar":"123","foo":123}
```

It looks like older versions of JSON has [autoconvert](https://metacpan.org/module/MAKAMAKA/JSON-1.12/lib/JSON.pm#AUTOCONVERT) functionality that can be set. Did you not have `$JSON::AUTOCONVERT` set to a true value?

Comment: You're quoting the wrong bit of the documentation; that's for JSON decoding, not encoding.

Comment: Nice catch. I removed that part of my answer.

Comment: +1 that is exactly the test i made. question: why does json1 create {"bar":"123","foo":"123"} here?

Comment: @Thariama, because the value for foo is a number, it does not quote it. The value for bar is cast into a string, so it is quoted. Is it possible that you have the autoconvert flag set? See my updated answer.

Comment: yes it is on, i checked my perl example program. the json1 documentation claimes that "By default, $JSON::AUTOCONVERT is true."

Answer (score 8):

It will be unquoted if it's a number. Without getting too deeply into Perl internals, something is a number if it's a literal number or the result of an arithmetic operation, *and it hasn't been stringified since its numeric value was produced*.

```
use JSON::XS;
my $json = JSON::XS->new->allow_nonref;

say $json->encode(42);   # 42
say $json->encode("42"); # "42"

my $x = 4;
say $json->encode($x); # 4
my $y = "There are $x lights!";
say $json->encode($x); # "4"
$x++; # modifies the numeric value of $x
say $json->encode($x); # 5
```

Note that printing a number isn't "stringifying it" even though it produces a string representation of the number to output; `print $x` doesn't cause a number to be a string, but `print "$x"` does.

Anyway, all of this is a bit weird, but if you want a value to be reliably unquoted in JSON then put `0 + $value` into your structure immediately before encoding it, and if you want it to be reliably quoted then use `"" . $value` or `"$value"`.

Comment: +1 i made a test and found out that JSON1 unqotes '12345', even though it has been a String before parsing. question: why does json1 create {"bar":"123","foo":"123"} here?