# Differentiate string and number argument in perl

Tags: perl

How to solve the following?

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use Test::Simple tests => 4;

ok( doit(0123)   == 83, "arg as octal number" );
ok( doit(83)     == 83, "arg as decimal number" );
ok( doit('0123') == 83, "arg as string with leading zero" );
ok( doit('123')  == 83, "arg as string without leading zero" );

sub doit {
    my $x = shift;
    return $x;                                     # how to replace this line
    #return  got_the_arg_as_string ? oct($x) : $x; # with something like this
}
```

E.g. If i pass to the `doit` sub any string - mean quoted value - (with or without the leading zero), it should be converted to octal value. Otherwise, it is just an number.

Comment: Wondering why you want such interface, where the quoted and unquoted arguments behaves differently. For me this looks like an source of future bugs...

Comment: @cajwine: that contradicts what you say in the question where you want doit('123') to be considered octal too ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perl's internal representation of a scalar may be as in integer or a string, and it remains ready to coerce that representation into any other scalar type at any moment. It is possible with C/XS code to get at a scalar's internal type. The [`JSON::XS`](http://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) module does this, for example, to decide whether a value should be rendered as a number or as a string.

Here's a proof of concept for your problem:

```
use Inline 'C';
sub foo {
    my ($x) = @_;
    print $x, " => isString: ", isString($x), "\n";
}
foo(0123);
foo('0123');

__END__
int isString(SV* sv)
{
    return SvPOK(sv) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
83 => isString: 0
0123 => isString: 1
```

Related posts:

[Difference between $var = 500 and $var = '500'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332808/difference-between-var-500-and-var-500/17348256#17348256)

[When does the difference between a string and a number matter in Perl 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980550/when-does-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-number-matter-in-perl-5)

[Why does the JSON module quote some numbers but not others?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17068764/why-does-the-json-module-quote-some-numbers-but-not-others)

**Update** some of this functionality is exposed in the core [`B`](http://metacpan.org/pod/B) module, so no need to add as XS dependency:

```
use B;
sub isString {
    my $scalar = shift;
    return 0 != (B::svref_2object(\$scalar)->FLAGS & B::SVf_POK)
}
```

Comment: `sub isNumber { no warnings "numeric"; length($_[0] & "") }`

Comment: Ahh yes!!! The `use B` derived `isString` is *exactly* for what me looking. The @ysth 's `isNumber` works too, but the `isString` is nearly twice as fast. GREAT! thank you. ;)

Comment: @FlorianB https://stackoverflow.com/a/3806159/17389